# What do ASP.NET performance counters mean?

Tags: asp.net, performance, performancecounter, perfmon

I'm trying to get a better handle on how threads work in ASP.NET, so I have a test site with a few pages, and I have a test WinForms client that creates 40 roughly concurrent requests to the test site. The requests take about 5-10 seconds to complete--they call a web service on another server. When I run the test client, I can use Fiddler to see that the requests are being made concurrently. However, when I look at Performance Monitor on the web server, with counters "ASP.NET Apps v2.0.xxx/Requests Executing", "ASP.NET/Requests Current", "ASP.NET Requests Queued", these counters never display more than 2. This is the case regardless of whether the test page I'm requesting is set up with Async=True and using the Begin/End pattern of calling the web service, or if it's set up to make the call synchronously. Judging by what I see in Fiddler, I would think I should be seeing a total of 40 requests in one of those states, but I don't. Why is that? Do these counters not mean what I think they mean?